# selecting with nvl function

Tags: sql, oracle, report, nvl

i have this query :

```
 select w.worker_id,   w.lastname,pd.invalid
                             from workers w,personal_data pd
                             where pd.worker_id (+) = w.worker_id
                             and nvl(pd.invalid,'N')='Y'
```

i have check box (y,n), purpose of the check box is to get list with invalids if its checked and when its not checked  with normal workers including  invalids. With this i always get invalid list.

And with this select :

```
  select w.worker_id,   w.lastname,pd.invalid
                                 from workers w,personal_data pd
                                 where pd.worker_id (+) = w.worker_id
                                 and pd.invalid =nvl(:p_invalid,pd_invalid)
```

if checkbox is Y i get invalid workers and when is not checked (n) i get just normal workers, i need to get when is N all workers ( invalid and normal ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using `(+)` syntax!  Use proper, explicit outer joins.

However, I don't think you need an outer join -- your comparison to a constant undoes it anyway.  I think this does what you want:

```
select w.worker_id, w.lastname, pd.invalid
from workers w join
     personal_data pd
    on pd.worker_id = w.worker_id
where (:p_invalid = 'N' or pd.invalid = :p_invalid);
```

Comment: from your select I still get just normal workers when checkbox is N

Comment: @mikrimouse . . . Okay.  Does `:p_invalid` take on `NULL` values or only "Y" and "N"?  If `NULL`, is that equivalent to "Y" or "N".  I changed the answer, assuming that `:p_invalid` is never `NULL`.

Comment: i changed it when i saw it ;), but it works ... thanks

Comment: @mikrimouse . . . If the value is not `NULL`, then that is not a natural approach.  In addition, I prefer `COALESCE()` because the latter is standard SQL.